# SQL: insert only new records

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2007

This must be very trivial but I can't seem to find the solution.

I work with two tables, both without any primary key.

I want to add all the records of the first table to the second table only if they don't exist.

Basically:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table
WHERE "the record to be added doesn't already exists in Table2"
```

Comment: so put a unique index on all the fields in both tables. do your query without a where clause - the index will reject any table1 records that would cause a duplicate key violation in table2

Comment: Fist select the rows in Table1 whose IDs don't exist in Table2 (with an EXISTS IN or Join) then insert them into table2

Comment: @MarcB The problem is that I don't have any control over the first table. Panagiotis there is no ID field.

Comment: Are both of these tables linked ODBC tables or is one of the tables a native Access table? If the latter, which table are you inserting into? Also, is MySQL actually involved in this? (Your recent questions have been about ODBC connections to Oracle.)

Comment: I can only connect to the ODBC table from a dedicated computer. I then update a native Access table with the records from the ODBC table so that I can work on it from a computer not connected to the ODBC table.
SQL is involved because I can't connect to the ODBC table using Access because of a field name containing a '/' so I have to use a passthrough SQL querry. I don't know if that's of any help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this. You would need to check each relevant column - I have just put in 2 as an example. With a `Not Exists` clause you can check if a record already existed across multiple columns. With a `NOT IN` you would only be able to check if a record already existed against one column.

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
      SELECT 1 
      FROM table2 t2 WHERE 
      t2.col1 = t1.col1 AND 
      t2.col2 = t1.col2
)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way not to check all the columns manually as I want all of them to be the criteria?

Comment: @Leo Unfortunately not. If you want to ensure you are not inserting duplicate data - you will need to check all the relevant fields.

Comment: May I ask what the `1` means after `SELECT`?

Comment: @Leo The `EXISTS` clause is checking for the existence of a record - not a particular value. Returning `SELECT 1` in the SELECT is more efficient than say returning the whole row via a `SELECT *`.

Comment: I did just as you said but the request is VERY slow (around 14000 rows and 7 fields). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Full query:
`INSERT INTO [Well Tests] 
SELECT t1.* 
FROM [PDMS Well Tests] t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM [Well Tests] t2 
    WHERE 
        t2.WELL = t1.WELL AND 
        t2.DATE_STAMP = t1.DATE_STAMP AND 
        t2.HOURS_TEST_DATA = t1.HOURS_TEST_DATA AND 
        t2.CHOKE_SIZE = t1.CHOKE_SIZE AND 
        t2.WELL_HEAD_PRESS = t1.WELL_HEAD_PRESS AND 
        t2.WELL_HEAD_TEMP = t1.WELL_HEAD_TEMP AND 
        t2.PRODUCED_BSW = t1.PRODUCED_BSW AND 
        t2.PGLR = t1.PGLR AND 
        t2.BFPD = t1.BFPD AND 
        t2.BOPD = t1.BOPD AND 
        t2.BWPD = t1.BWPD
)`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I use Access to connect to an ODBC database.

Comment: May i serve you a SQL exec time comparsion of this problem: http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/fastest-way-to-insert-new-records-where-one-doesnt-already-exist

Answer (score 1):

you could make usage of the `EXISTS` function:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE <your expression to compare the two tables goes here>)
```

But i would advise you to check the use of unique index for your tables

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - untested:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Field1 = Table1.Field1 AND Table2.Field2 = Table1.Field2)
```

You must add every Field of both Tables in the WHERE clause of the NOT EXISTS Query

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO X.TableX1
 (ColumX1,ColumnX2)
 
SELECT DISTINCT c.[ColumnY1],c.[ColumnY2] 
 FROM Y.Table2 c INNER JOIN Database.z.Table3 i ON c.ColumnX1= i.ColumnY1 

WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
      SELECT *
      FROM X.TableX1 WHERE 
      X.TableX1.ColumnX1=c.ColumnY1
)
```

This is Joining two tables and filtering the data required and updating only the new values to third table on every run